# change position of one background image in a multi backgrounded div

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-position

I have a simple HTML : `<div id="wrapper"></div>` and this style sheet:

```
#wrapper{

        position: absolute;

        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;     

        background-image: url(img1.png), url(img2.png);

        background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;

        background-position: top center, center center;

        background-color: green;
        border: 1px solid black;

}
```

as above style sheet shows `#wrapper` has two background images in different positions.
I want to change **second** image position on mouse click **with applying no change on the first image position**. what syntax do i have to use?

my jquery code :

```
$("#wrapper").click(function(){
    this.css("background-position": " ? , bottom right " );
});
```

i think `?` should be replaced with something like `!important` but `!important` does not works for applying no change on first image.

position of both background images will change in different places, and i dont know what is the first image position now, i can save its position in a variable, but i rather to use native solution, if exists
any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change background position 2

This will replace the second background position (after comma) with `bottom right`:

```
$('#wrapper').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-position', function() {
        return this.style.backgroundPosition.replace(/,(.*)$/, ', bottom right');
    });
});
```

change background position 1

And this will replace the first background position (before comma) with `bottom right`:

```
$('#wrapper').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-position', function() {
        return this.style.backgroundPosition.replace(/(.*),/, 'bottom right, ');
    });
});
```

this solution is a good choice if element has only two backgrounds and we want to change position or any other property of each background images

Comment: what does this `return this.style.backgroundPosition.replace(/,(.*)$/, ', center center');` do?

Comment: and how can i use this solution to change first image position? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple backgrounds, the backgrounds and all other properties involving the backgrounds, are comma seperated lists, so all you have to do is use the same CSS rule as is already applied to "not" make any changes to the first background image's position:

```
$("#wrapper").on('click', function(){
    $(this).css("background-position", "top center, bottom right");
});
```

Another option would be to set the background-position in classes, and just swap classes:

```
.bg1 {background-position: top center, center center;}
.bg2 {background-position: top center, bottom right;}
```

-

```
$("#wrapper").on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('bg1 bg2');
});
```

Comment: position of both background images will change in different places, and i dont know what is the first image position now, i can save its position in a variable, but i rather to use native solution, if exists

Comment: Then you probably have to go for something like Michal Klouda's answer! Personally I never use multiple backgrounds, I'd rather use two elements.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to explicitly specify both images' position (even the one that doesn't change, since there's no way, so far as I yet know, to keep track of which image is which):

```
$('#wrapper').click(
    function(){
        $(this).css({
            'background-position': 'top center, center center'
        });
    });
```

Also, note that the native DOM `this` isn't able to use jQuery methods, you have to use the jQuery `$(this)` object.

Comment: thank you, position of both background images will change in different places, and i dont know what is the first image position now, i can save its position in a variable, but i rather to use native solution, if exists

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the original value of first position and then reassign it together with your second value changed..

```
$("#wrapper").click(function(){
   var first = $(this).css("background-position").split(',')[0];
   $(this).css("background-position", first + ", bottom right " );
});
```

Comment: Be aware that most browsers will return the values as percentages, and not 'top center', but it should still work !

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS:

```
body {

  background-image:
    url(https://...image1),
    url(https://...image2);

  background-position:
    top 10% left 10%,
    top 10% right 10%;
}
```